# Как увеличить разрешение экрана при котором появляется бургер?

Tags: css, bootstrap

Как увеличить разрешение экрана при котором появляется бургер. По умолчанию он появляется при <992px, а мне нужно увеличить это значение, использую Bootstrap 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете прописать любые стили которые захотите. Если необходимо использовать стили только на одной странице, то используйте "Глобальные стили". Они будут более приоритетные, чем стили bootstrap.

Comment: Либо можно класс .col-xl-  использовать вместо .col-lg-

Answer (score 1):

Откройте файл bootstrap.css
В самом начале файла найдите строку:  --breakpoint-lg: 992px; Вписываете своё значение, сохраняете файл, радуетесь -))